# Elastic Search: Combining multiple search results

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch

i have a tricky case which I dont know how to solve.

I have 2 queries: q1 and q2
The 2 queries result in r1 and r2

each of the results is sorted in a special order.

As an overall search result i want to return a concatenation of r1+r2 *before* returning it to the application.

The reason is that i would break the pagination if I do it later.

Any idea? Its probalby an easy question but I am stuck on this...

PS:

we also experimented with sorting first by a priary sort criteria and then by the score.. but the score always breaks the first sort criteria somehow we cant get the score working only within its bucket.

Comment: plz add this information to your question - not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

you can boost your fruits with a factor, so that their score will be always higher than the vegetable score, yet preserving the order. You can do that with a simple `weight` [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#score-functions)

```
PUT /test

POST /test/fruits/1
{
    "field": "hello world"
}

POST /test/fruits/2
{
    "field":"hello"
}

POST /test/veges/1
{
    "field": "hello world"
}

POST /test/veges/2
{
    "field":"hello"
}

POST /test/_search
{

    "query": {

        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                   "field": "hello"
                }   
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "type": {
                           "value": "fruits"
                        }
                    },
                    "weight": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

However please note that if you do that on a big database then it will be very resource consuming to page down to the first vegetable. I would consider rebuilding your UX so that fruits and vegetables are actually separate requests. You can do that with a _bulk endpoint and send two separate queries per each document type in one server API call, and return both results back.

Answer (score 0):

It would suggest to use [Combining query feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html) of Elastic search;

Comment: thank you for your answer.. we tried, but it does not do what we are aiming to. i give you a concrete example. you have a database table full of fruits and a database table full of vegtable. I want to first get all fruits and order them by a defined score which considers color and weight. I want to do the same with the vegtables but i need to make sure that all fruits will come first orderd by the score and then all vegtables come ordered by the score. Therefore the total result it is not ordered by score (the lowers fruit score is smaller than the highest vegtable score) but the 2 buckets are